# How to determine if a date range contains a Saturday

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

In my dataset, I have a start datetime field and an end datetime field.

I need to determine if there is a Saturday in this date range (would only need to check for one occurrence as this date range is max 3 days).

For example the below date range - there is **one** Saturday (the 18th) in this range. I would like to set some sort of flag to indicate that there is a Saturday in the range.

begin_date - 2023-03-17 08:04:02.000,
end_date   - 2023-03-20 23:17:30.000

Thank you

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own set of date/time functions.)

Comment: Date functionality is intrinsically platform-dependent; Please read the [TAG Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) of the TAG you have used and then edit your question as appropriate.

Comment: This is on SQL Server V18

Comment: There's no SQL Server v18 yet. The latest release, SQL Server 2022, is only v16. Perhaps you're looking at the version of the SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) tool, so what's the output of the query `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: If the date range is max 3 days, then the start date needs to be at between Thursday (sat-2) and Saturday, and the end date between Saturday and Monday

Comment: If the range is always max of 3 days you don't need to use the end date at all, just check if start date is thurs - sat.

Comment: I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5015371) - 13.0.7016.1 (X64)   May 21 2022 01:00:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Stu maybe I didnt sketch the scenario too well - so this is about call centre agents who handle customer issues - They can work on an issue for anything from 1 minute upwards, up to a max of three days. The Sql function I use to calculate the time spent on the issue, only makes provision for full working weekdays, so I  need to go and check if they worked on a Saturday - whereby I need to add the time worked on Saturday as well. Hence the need to be able to check if there is a Saturday in their time spent - whether they worked 5 minutes or 3 days.

Comment: IF your question needs clarity, please edit it, comments are not always read or visible. I don't see how what you said above changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a function like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_HAS_SATURDAY (@pFrom DATE, @pTo DATE)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
 
    RETURN (
        CASE 
            WHEN    DATEDIFF(DAY, @pFrom, @pTo) >= 6    -- 6 days or more must pass on saturday
            OR  (DATEPART(DW, @pFrom) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 = 6 -- start is saturday
            OR  (DATEPART(DW, @pTo) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 = 6 -- end is saturday
            OR (
                (DATEPART(DW, @pFrom) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 -- overlapping stuff
            >   (DATEPART(DW, @pTo) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 
            AND (DATEPART(DW, @pFrom) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 < 6
            )
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    

END

Go
 DECLARE @assert TABLE (dt datetime, dt_to datetime, has_sat bit)
 INSERT INTO @assert
 VALUES ('2023-03-17 08:04:02.000', '2023-03-20 23:17:30.000', 1)
 ,  ('2023-05-12', '2023-05-12 23:17:30.000', 0)
 ,  ('2023-05-14', '2023-05-16 23:17:30.000', 0)
 ,  ('2023-05-08', '2023-05-12', 0)
 ,  ('2023-05-11', '2023-05-13', 1)
 ,  ('2023-05-13 13:00', '2023-05-13', 1)
 ,  ('2023-05-13 13:00', '2023-05-19 23:17:30.000', 1)
 ,  ('2023-05-14 13:00', '2023-05-19 23:17:30.000', 0)
 ,  ('2023-05-14 13:00', '2023-05-20 23:17:30.000', 1)
 ,  ('2023-05-14 13:00', '2023-05-21 23:17:30.000', 1)


SELECT  *, dbo.FN_HAS_SATURDAY(dt, dt_to)
FROM    @assert
WHERE   has_sat <> dbo.FN_HAS_SATURDAY(dt, dt_to)
```

I got it down to 4 conditions to cover the various cases, maybe someone can optimize a couple of them away, but dating are hard.

You can also convert it to inline function to get better performance or just reuse the case when. Note that i cast the dates to DATE, since times are irrelevant here

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask about the syntax - ie in ' (DATEPART(DW, @pFrom) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 ' what does it mean, specifically the '%' part. Thanks

Comment: yeah, it's a bit tricky. The datepart(dw, somedate) returns the day number for the specific day. For example, monday is first, tuesday is second. This allows to check which date is saturday. The *problem* is that, different database server settings means that on different system, first day is not always monday, sometimes sunday is considered first. This makes it complicated to use this code, because it might be wrong on another computer.

Comment: Here's where @@datefirst come in, it returns the current setting for which day is considered first. By doing the whole formula with + 5 and % 7 (modulo division) + 1, one always gets a stable,monday is first value back. I haven't found a good article to explain it, but you can google set datefirst to read more about it